# Issue with enforcing referential integrity In Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, relationships, table-relationships

So I was mapping out the relationships between tables in a database I'm working on but I ran into some problems.

It was recommended to me that I use the "Enforce Referential Integrity" function when working with table relationships but everytime I try and and make more than one relationship between tables it gives me the error: "No unique index found for the referenced field of the Primary table".

If I don't use the "Enforce Referential Integrity" function then it seems to work fine. Will it negativity effect my table if I don't use the function and if yes then how can I solve the error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of referential integrity is data integrity, if you won't enforce it, the data may become inconsistent, may appear logical errors, so enforcing is highly recommended. Additionally you can enable cascading and the data from detail table will be deleted or updated automatically if you delete/update the key field in main table.

As of error, it means that your main table should have primary key or unique index on fields you map to detail table. If main table has primary key with few fields, all those fields should be mapped to detail table.

Please post the picture of your relationships map and describe which fields should be mapped.

Comment: Try to start with Address-Members, it should work OK, Series-Races, Racers-RacersInRace, Racers-RacersInRace, Training-TrainingMembers also should be OK. The rest won't work. 

Delete MemberName relations from everywhere, you don't need it because you have unique MemberID key, it should be enough. In RacersInRace add RacerID column to primary key

Comment: Thank you for your help, One problem is that the MemberName field is quite important to the database and if I can't use it with relationships then I would have to put the field into every table?. Is there a way around that (Also what is the technical reason why it wont work?). Also what's the reason for adding a primary key to RacerID?.

Comment: You can keep Member Name along with Member ID in other tables, it called denormalization, may cause data integrity errors when the same MemberID has different MemberName. I would recommend to pull MemberName from Members table each time when you need this. The second way - you can add MemberName to primary key in Members table. In this case you will be able to enforce referential integrity, add update cascade and data will be consistent.

Comment: If you won't add RacerID to RacersInRace, you won't be able to add more than one racer to each race

Comment: So in the RacersInRace table I just need to add RacerID to the Primary key. Also I took your advice and removed all the MemberName relations.